# Moving space from swap to /

Tags: disk, fdisk

I have a 4GB sd card but what i'd like to be able to do is have more free space on the / partition I don't actually need a swap partition either so how would i resize/move partitions for example using fdisk?

```
Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 3.7 GiB

Device         Boot   Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/mmcblk0p1 *       2048 3844095 3842048  1.9G 83 Linux
/dev/mmcblk0p2      3846142 7772159 3926018  1.9G  5 Extended
/dev/mmcblk0p5      3846144 7772159 3926016  1.9G 82 Linux swap / Solaris

Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            920M     0  920M   0% /dev
tmpfs           187M   20M  168M  11% /run
/dev/mmcblk0p1  1.8G  1.3G  417M  76% /
tmpfs           935M     0  935M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           935M     0  935M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           187M     0  187M   0% /run/user/1001
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Stop the swap using `swapoff -a`
2. Remove the swap (`/dev/mmcblk0p5`) and the extended (`/dev/mmcblk0p2`) partitions. To remove a partition with fdisk just run `fdisk /dev/mmcblk0` and use `d` to delete a partition (it will ask which one).
3. Don't forget to remove swap entry from `/etc/fstab` and GRUB config.
4. Resize the `/` partition. Resizing a partition with fdisk means deleting it and then creating a new one with same start sector and different end sector. You can follow for example [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/139468/196468).
5. Don't forget to resize the filesystem on `/dev/mmcblk0p1` after you resize it. Use tool for your filesystem `resize2fs /dev/mmcblk0p1` for Ext4 or `xfs_growfs /dev/mmcblk0p1` for XFS.

As always with storage, make sure to make a backup first.

Comment: That worked perfectly many thanks

    Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
    udev            920M     0  920M   0% /dev
    tmpfs           187M  3.2M  184M   2% /run
    /dev/mmcblk0p1  3.7G  1.3G  2.2G  37% /
    tmpfs           935M     0  935M   0% /dev/shm
    tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
    tmpfs           935M     0  935M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
    tmpfs           187M     0  187M   0% /run/user/1001