# How many partitions can have a 'boot' flag?

Tags: linux, partition, dual-boot, gparted

I'm trying to correctly partition my hard-drive to facilitate a dual-boot setup Windows 10/Linux Mint 18.3

I'm using a brand new laptop and completed the out-of-box-experience so Windows 10 was installed. I then inserted the Gparted live CD and rebooted.

I shrinked down /dev/sda3 which was the ntfs windows partition to 100GiB with the msftdata flag. This process left me with approximately 350GiB unallocated space.

I selected the un-allocated space and created 3 primary partitions (the other options were grayed out):

One of these partition with Fat16 Filesystem of 150MiB I gave the boot, esp flags. The other two partitions were linux-swap and ext4 based partition for general storage.

The question that is bothering me is:

Is it ok to have two separate partitions on the one hard drive with the boot,esp flags? One partition for windows boot and one partition for Linux boot?

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/23588/70524. Also, since you mention ESP and a pre-installed Windows 10, presumably you have a UEFI system, in which case [setting the boot flag in `parted` marks that partition as the ESP](https://www.gnu.org/software/parted/manual/html_node/set.html). But there should already have been an ESP from the Windows installation, so something is messed up. Please add the output of `sudo parted -l` to the post.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boot_flag